# Show that any finite simple non-abelian group is not solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solvable-groups

Aluffi's Algebra claims (implicitly) that any finite simple non-abelian group is not solvable. 
On the other hand, it defines a group to be not solvable if its derived series doesn't terminate with the identity. 
How to show that a finite simple non-abelian group is not solvable based on the original definition it gives?

PS The derived series of $G$ is the sequence of subgroups $G ⊇ G' ⊇ G'' ⊇ G''' ⊇ \dots$ . $G' = [G,G]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we know that **always** $\;G'\lhd G\;$ , so if the group $\;G\;$ is *non-abelian simple*...what is then $\;G'\;$ ?

Comment: This is not quite finished, so I just wanted to add a bit. $G$ is simple so $G'$ must be the trivial subgroup or $G$ itself. If it is the trivial subgroup of $G$, then $ a^{-1} b^{-1} a b = 1 \iff ab = ba$, which implies that $G$ would be abelian, which was false by assumption.